# 2006 honda civic new starter but still clicks new battery but wll run once jump started

Tags: honda, civic

I have a 2006 Honda Civic with clicking sounds from the starter like its not engaging or is stuck. I have installed 2 starters and changed earth leads with same outcome. Thought it could be battery but What else could be causing this?

Comment: Please edit your question to add some punctuation so we can make sense of what you are trying to say.

Comment: jump starting works?

Comment: dirty battery terminals?